# Swift Tab view show more than one page 3 or 5 pages

Tags: swiftui, tabview

I am trying to view List of objects in swiftui using Tabview, can I view more than one tab at same time??

You can check my code here:

```
 import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 14, *)
struct CustomListWithPosition: View {
    @Binding var itemsList: [ItemForPicker]
    @Binding var selectedId: Int
    @State private var visibleRows: [ItemForPicker] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedId) {
              Group {
                  ForEach(itemsList, id:\.id) { item in
                      Text("\(item.title)")
                          .frame(height: 44)
                          .foregroundColor(selectedId == item.id ? .yellow : .black)
                          .id(item.id)
                          .tag(item.id)
                  }
              }
              .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -90))
        }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90))
            .frame(height: 200)
     }
  }


struct ItemForPicker : Hashable  {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
}
```

Thanx for your time.

Comment: may you share us a screenshot of what you likely want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can surely view multiples view at the same time with TabView(), but displaying multiple views should not use with TabView() as it is not an ideal for viewing multiple views in the same screen; it would break the main purpose of TabView().

example:

you can do it like this, but it is not good.

```
 var body: some View {
    //not an ideal to do it
    TabView {
        HStack {
            Group {
                //display your objects
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should use List{}, VStack{}, ScrollView{}, HStack{} to display multiple views in your main view instead.

Comment: This will not work, at least not for what was requested by PO - just in case.

Comment: Oh I thought it worked as I created some multiple Dummy views to test the HStack inside the TabView for him, Asperi.